# Read the last line of tzselect

Tags: bash, timezone

I am trying to read the result of tzselect into a bash script in order to set the Timezone pragmatically.

Code snippet should look like

```
/usr/bin/tzselect
#Read last line of tzselect and cp to /etc/localtime
cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/$RESULT /etc/localtime
ntpdate -u 0.centos.pool.ntp.org
hwclock --systohc
#Following lines are just confirmation that the times are the same.
date
hwclock
```

Comment: To save TZ to a file: `tzselect  | tail -n1 > <FILE>`. To save TZ to $VAR: `VAR=$(tzselect  | tail -n1 )`.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk under what circumstances can `tzselect` return more than one line? Curious, thank you.

Comment: @roaima: probably never, I just didn't notice that `tzselect` prompts via stderr and only prints output to stdout :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tzselect` prompts via stdin/stderr, with the result going to stdout. This means it's straightforward to capture in a variable

```
NEW_TIMEZONE=$(tzselect)
test -n "$NEW_TIMEZONE" && cp -fp /usr/share/zoneinfo/"$NEW_TIMEZONE" /etc/localtime
```

Comment: I would add a plus 1 for the error correcting, but I don't have enough rep yet. I'm now using a combo of this answer and Ark's comment ( | tail -n1 )

Comment: For those using centos 6.5 the path is /usr/share/zoneinfo instead. Gotta love the e

Comment: Ah. that's a typo on my part. I'll update my answer thank you.